# Read fstring from a range of 01 to 10

Tags: python, loops

(I don't know how to entitle the topic in a better way, if someone has a better idea, feel free to edit the title. )

Are there any ways to read files from a range of 01 to 10?

For example, I am reading a file from `1-01-1, 1-02-1... 1-10-1`. Absolutely, I am using for loop to read it. However, I got some problems here.
If I write

```py
for i in range(1,10):
    file = f"1-0{i}-1.wav"
```

It shows an error of not finding "1-010-1.wav"

If I omit the `0` in the middle of the name, like

```py
for i in range(1,10):
    file = f"1-{i}-1.wav"
```

It shows not finding the file "1-1-1.wav".

I hope there's an efficient way to deal with it!

Comment: try glob module. you can use regex type search.
ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0):

Format strings support padding, like this:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    file = f"1-{i:02}-1.wav"
```

`{i:02}` means "make it at least 2 chars long by prepending zeros when needed". The shorter version is `{i:2}`, because zero is the default padding character.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I haven't thought it before!